# .mp3 & .wav Files in Xcode

Tags: xcode, mp3, audio

I got the following setup in xcode but no sound is coming out. i had 2 .wav files work before but other .mp3 and .wav files wont work, im wondering if its the code thats been written up or if its the sound files? is there any restrictions with the bit rate or size of the files? see below for code. I also add the sound files into the project.

```
**ViewController.h** 
import UIKit/UIKit.h

import AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h

import AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h

@interface ViewController :UIViewController 


-(IBAction)AntlerRabbit;



@end


**ViewController.m**

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(IBAction)AntlerRabbit {

CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();

CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;

soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"AntlerRabbit",         CFSTR("aiff"), NULL);

UInt32 soundID;

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I then go to MainStoryboard.storyboard and place a button and link it to 'AntlerRabbit' but nothing happens in the simulator

Answer (score 0):

The answer was here:

[Using Audio in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html)

The reason why no sound was playing in the simulator is because when you use,

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound
```

the sound needs to be a maximum of 30 seconds in length. The sound i was using was just a bit above it. If anyone knows how to use a sounds file more than 30 seconds please post the code :) would be much appreciated.